# MySQL jBPM 6.2 deployment error

Tags: mysql, drools, jbpm, kie-workbench, kie-wb

After solving for couple of issues to switch H2 with MySQL for jBPM 6.2; followed the instructions to modify  [3.6.3. Using your own database](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html) .
 i am stuck at this error that is thrown while deployment . 
has anybody solved for this, i could'nt find any fix.
My env: 
Wildfly 8.1
Jbpm 6.2 Final
MySQL 5.7.9

Here's the stack trace from the .FAILED file.

```
"{\"JBAS014671: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".WeldStartService\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceLifeCycleController.init() on org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceLifeCycleController@2742ef77
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:91)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BeanInjectionTarget.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:162)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78)
    at org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceLifeCycleController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:122)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:128)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:396)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:93)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:89)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to commit transaction
    at org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionManager.commit(JtaTransactionManager.java:229)
    at org.jbpm.shared.services.impl.TransactionalCommandService.execute(TransactionalCommandService.java:43)
    at org.jbpm.executor.impl.jpa.ExecutorRequestAdminServiceImpl.requeue(ExecutorRequestAdminServiceImpl.java:77)
    at org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceImpl.requeue(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:218)
    at org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceImpl.init(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:131)
    at org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceLifeCycleController.init(ExecutorServiceLifeCycleController.java:38)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1178)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.commit(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:173)
    at org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionManager.commit(JtaTransactionManager.java:226)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: setRollbackOnly called from:
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImple.java:314)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.setRollbackOnly(BaseTransaction.java:159)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.setRollbackOnly(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.markForRollbackOnly(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1544)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.handlePersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1660)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1764)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at org.jbpm.shared.services.impl.JpaPersistenceContext.queryInTransaction(JpaPersistenceContext.java:58)
    at org.jbpm.executor.impl.jpa.ExecutorRequestAdminServiceImpl$RequeueRunningJobsCommand.execute(ExecutorRequestAdminServiceImpl.java:103)
    at org.jbpm.executor.impl.jpa.ExecutorRequestAdminServiceImpl$RequeueRunningJobsCommand.execute(ExecutorRequestAdminServiceImpl.java:85)
        at 

org.jbpm.shared.services.impl.TransactionalCommandService.execute(TransactionalCommandService.java:42)
        ... 42 more
    \"}}"
```